# How to set AWS Cognito custom user pool attributes as read-only for a client?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I'm having problems setting my custom attributes to read-only with CDK/CloudFormation/CLI. They are defined in the user pool and mutable and I'm able to do it in the console just fine but not in any other way.

I've tried with CDK (java) with

```
ClientAttributes writeAttributes = new ClientAttributes();
```

and

```
ClientAttributes writeAttributes = new ClientAttributes().withCustomAttributes();
```

and the corresponding CloudFormation YAML

```
WriteAttributes:[]
```

but they are still writable. If I try to target a single attribute instead of just all blank I get a "Invalid write attributes specified while updating a client". The same result regardless of CDK, CloudFormation YAML or CLI (adjusted with "custom:"-prefix depending on method of attempt)

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

- Nik

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest version of the AWS CDK and check for any updates in the AWS documentation.

As per the CDK API Reference documentation, you can set the read-only scope in the following manner:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/cognito/package-summary.html#resource-servers-heading

Also I am providing the code snippet as below which can help you:

```
// Required import statements
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.App;
import ....
import ....

public class TestCognitoStack extends Stack {

public TestCognitoStack(final App parent, final String name) {
    super(parent, name);

    // Create a Cognito User Pool
    UserPool userPool = ....

    // Add custom attributes to the User Pool
    userPool.addCustomAttribute("...");

    // Create a User Pool Client
    UserPoolClient userPoolClient = ...

    // Make custom attributes read-only
    ClientAttributes readOnlyAttributes = ClientAttributes.builder()
            .customAttributes(Map.of("customAttribute1", true, "customAttribute2", true))
            .build();
    userPoolClient.setWriteAttributes(readOnlyAttributes);
  }

}
```

In this example, the setWriteAttributes method is used to set the custom attributes as read-only for the User Pool Client. Make sure to replace the placeholder values with your actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, it turned out to be missing standard attributes, apparently you have to list them as writable:

```
        ClientAttributes writeAttributes = new ClientAttributes()
                .withStandardAttributes(StandardAttributesMask.builder().givenName(true).familyName(true).email(true).phoneNumber(true).build())
                .withCustomAttributes();
```

what threw me off was that the error started appearing when I added stuff to the .withCustomAttributes() even if the root cause was in .withStandardAttributes(). One might think that it would tell you *which* attribute failed but no...